# Project euler 8: weird issue

Tags: c#

I've tried solving Project Euler [Problem 8](http://projecteuler.net/problem=8)
I believe I have the right approach, but for some reason I get the exception ("An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll") in below code when `i=494`.
Line is 38 I believe.
PS. The length of the string is 1000 as shown by debugger too.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace euler8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           const String candidate =   "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"+
                                      "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"+
                                      "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"+
                                      "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"+
                                      "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"+
                                      "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"+
                                      "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"+
                                      "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"+
                                      "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"+
                                      "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"+
                                      "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"+
                                      "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"+
                                      "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"+
                                      "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"+
                                      "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"+
                                      "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"+
                                      "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"+
                                      "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"+
                                      "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"+
                                      "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

            long max = 0;
            int length = candidate.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < length - 13; i++)
            {
                string substring = candidate.Substring(i, i + 13);

                int [] x = new int [13];
                for(int j = 0; j<13; j++)
                    x[j]= int.Parse(substring[j].ToString());

                long product = 1;
                for (int k = 0; k < 13; k++)
                    product = product * x[k];

                if (product > max)
                    max = product;

            }

            Console.WriteLine(max.ToString());



        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone spot the issue?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would assume it has something to do with the fact that there are a lot of questions that have this particular structure: _"I wrote something, and it doesn't work. Here's the code."_ Eric Lippert [wrote an article about these questions](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), explaining how to debug these yourself. You've given a bit more information than these questions usually do, but you, too, could have solved the problem yourself by applying the techniques from the article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is stemming from a misunderstanding of how `.SubString()` works.

```
string substring = candidate.Substring(i, i + 13);
```

Most likely should be:

```
string substring = candidate.Substring(i, 13);
```

`.SubString()` is : `.SubString(startPosition, length)` So adding `i + 13` doesn't net you the next 13 characters, but instead the next `i + 13` characters from start position `i`.

Comment: @siva.k the signature you provide actually gives the impression that you _should_ pass `i + 13`. In reality it is `Substring( int startIndex, int length )`. [edit] Never mind, you changed it already. (Y)

Comment: @georgem searching for it says it's 40824

Answer (score 1):

[String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) needs a starting position plus a *length*, not and end position.

So just use

```
string substring = candidate.Substring(i, 13);
```